# Usage of "Il ne sert à rien de pleurer sur le lait renversé"

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes

Cherchant à rendre en français le proverbe anglais :

> *[It's no use crying over spilled milk](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-s-no-use-crying-over-spilled-milk)
> said to emphasize that it is not useful feeling sorry about something that has already happened.*

j'ai trouvé

> Il ne sert à rien de pleurer sur le lait renversé.

Peut-on le dire couramment en français ?

Comment: Note: il s'agit sans doute du *lait renversé*. Expression pas trop utilisée, mais que tout le monde comprendra. *Ce qui est fait est fait* convient peut-être mieux

Comment: @Damien Corrigé ; merci !

Comment: Il y a la fable « Perette et le pot au lait » qui me vient à l’esprit, mais qui ne correspond pas vraiment au sens anglais de « spilled milk »

Comment: Lait renversé est pas trop utilisé... voire pas du tout ! Les français utilisent jamais l’expression “lait renversé” . C’est juste une traduction mot à mot qui n’aurait pas de sens pour un interlocuteur français.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme le dit @Damien, on peut utiliser la formule :

> Ce qui est fait est fait.

on peut dire également :

> On ne récrit pas l'histoire.

Comment: Une variante: *ça ne sert à rien de revenir sur le passé*

Comment: Détail: on ne *réécrit* pas ...

Comment: @Damien Oops, didn't see you already came with something similar

Comment: @Damien: [pas forcément](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R1005)

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas ! (ou j'ai oublié). J'ignore quelle est la forme la plus utilisée

Comment: La forme la plus utilisée est **réécrire**, de loin : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%A9crire%2C+r%C3%A9%C3%A9crire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Reyedy: C'est juste une affaire de choix ou d'habitude, ce n'est pas parce c'est plus utilisé depuis les années 70 que cela devient une règle. Personnellement, j'ai appris « *récrire* » sur les bancs de l'école primaire.

Comment: Je répondais simplement au commentaire "j'ignore quelle est la forme la plus utilisée". Le débat sur l'usage, son importance dans la définition des règles, et le rôle d'arbitre de l'Académie Française, est trop vaste pour avoir lieu ici.

Comment: J'ai appris moi aussi *récrire* ainsi que *rouvrir*, qui est fortement attaqué ces derniers mois par *réouvrir*... @Reyedy https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%A9crire%2Cr%C3%A9%C3%A9crire%2Crouvrir%2C+r%C3%A9ouvrir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crouvrir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9ouvrir%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9%C3%A9crire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crouvrir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9ouvrir%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

I would also say something like

> C'est du passé, n'en parlons plus

Answer (score 1):

J'ai fréquemment entendu "Rien ne sert de pleurer" quand j'étais enfant, peut-être une forme courte de la locution "Rien ne sert de pleurer sur le lait renversé" que j'ai moins entendu mais qui ne me surprendrait pas du tout si je l'entendais.